# При наведении на елемент появляются другие елементы

Tags: css

Хочу сделать при наведении на елемент, что бы правее появлялись несколько  похожих елементов и пока я веду указатель мыши к появившимся елементам елементы не пропадали, но если я увожу указатель мыши слишком далеко, то появившиеся  елементы пропадают.

Фиолетовым на скриншоте обозначен елемент на который я хочу наводить указатель мыши
Красным обозначены точки где я хочу что бы появлялись елементы
Все что вне зоне видимости(вне скрине зона, уводя указатель мыши за которую появившиеся елементы должны пропадать)

[image: Пример]

Как это можно сделать? Или дайте пожалуйста ссылки подобного, не могу ничего найти, что могло бы помочь мне решить эту задачу

Answer (score 3):

Всего-то надо прописать `:hover` родительскому блоку, а не мелким блокам.

```css
.mama { display: inline-flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }

.bubu-hidden {
  display: none;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bubu-hidden:hover { background-color: #f36700; }

.bubu-hidden.visi { display: block; }

.mama:hover .bubu-hidden { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="mama">
  <div class="bubu-hidden visi"></div>
  <div class="bubu-hidden"></div>
  <div class="bubu-hidden"></div>
  <div class="bubu-hidden"></div>
</div>
```

`.bubu-hidden.visi` — запись без пробела. Означает "те элементы, у которых есть И первый, И второй класс".

`.mama:hover .bubu-hidden` — Через пробел, "при наведении на mama, где-то внутри найти все элементы с классом bubu-hidden"

https://webref.ru/css — см. "Селекторы". Через комбинацию селекторов можно делать всякие чудесатые вещи.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ. Я сделал это: https://youtu.be/YeVrt5p4c7c

Как я могу направить выпадание в правую сторону и выйти за границы ширины сайдбара?

```css
html {
 overflow: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #181f4b;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #969dcd;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 0px;
 background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background: #FF0000;
}

.unselectable {
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

.main-container {
 height: 100%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c58dd, #2a44c8);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
 z-index: 1;
}

.logo {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
 width: 40px;
}

nav {
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul:first-child,
.sidebar > nav > ul:nth-child(2) {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li > a {
 color: #6b83e2;
 display: block;
 width: 48px;
 height: 48px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 opacity: 0.3;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: relative;
}

.personal-office {
 margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > .personal-office > a {
 opacity: 1;
}

.personal-office > a > img:hover{
 transition: 1s;
 transform: rotateZ(360deg);
}

.account_avatar_image {
 width: 48px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: block;
}

.sing-in > a {
 background: url(/images/sing-in.png) no-repeat center;
}

.sing-out > a {
 background: url(https://i.imgur.com/YwT5mO8.png) no-repeat center;
}

.rules > a {
 background: url(https://i.imgur.com/N5pzODb.png) no-repeat center;
}

.sing-in > a:hover,
.sing-out > a:hover,
.rules > a:hover {
 opacity: 1;
 background-color:  #385ce2;
}

.filters {
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.filters:hover .a-z-background-hidden,
.filters:hover .a-z-hidden {
 display: block;
}

.filter-hidden {
 background: url(https://i.imgur.com/regS5LD.png) no-repeat center;
}

.filter-hidden {
 color: #6b83e2;
 display: none;
 width: 48px;
 height: 48px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 opacity: 0.3;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: relative;
}

.filter-hidden:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 1;
 background-color:  #385ce2;
}

.filter-hidden.visible {
 display: block;
}

.a-z-background-hidden {
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c58dd, #2a44c8);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 display: none;
 width: 48px;
 height: 48px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: relative;
}

.a-z-hidden {
 background: url(https://i.imgur.com/nBI2vJj.png) no-repeat center;
}

.a-z-hidden {
 color: #6b83e2;
 display: none;
 width: 48px;
 height: 48px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 opacity: 0.3;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: relative;
}

.vk > a {
 background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Mo1SCNB.png) no-repeat center;
}

.telegram > a {
 background: url(https://i.imgur.com/IRdCiwG.png) no-repeat center;
}

.vk > a:hover,
.telegram > a:hover {
 opacity: 1;
 background-color:  #385ce2;
}

.sidebar-bottom {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}

.content {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   v2.0-modified | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* make sure to set some focus styles for accessibility */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}

body {
 line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

input[type=search] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

textarea {
    overflow: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    resize: vertical;
}

/**
 * Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 */

audio,
canvas,
video {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/**
 * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */

audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 7/8/9, Firefox 3, and Safari 4.
 * Known issue: no IE 6 support.
 */

[hidden] {
    display: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct text resizing oddly in IE 6/7 when body `font-size` is set using
 *    `em` units.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */

html {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Address `outline` inconsistency between Chrome and other browsers.
 */

a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
}

/**
 * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 * 2. Improve image quality when scaled in IE 7.
 */

img {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Address margin not present in IE 6/7/8/9, Safari 5, and Opera 11.
 */

figure {
    margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Correct margin displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

form {
    margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Correct text not wrapping in Firefox 3.
 * 3. Correct alignment displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

legend {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    padding: 0;
    white-space: normal; /* 2 */
    *margin-left: -7px; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Correct font size not being inherited in all browsers.
 * 2. Address margins set differently in IE 6/7, Firefox 3+, Safari 5,
 *    and Chrome.
 * 3. Improve appearance and consistency in all browsers.
 */

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    margin: 0; /* 2 */
    vertical-align: baseline; /* 3 */
    *vertical-align: middle; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * Address Firefox 3+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */

button,
input {
    line-height: normal;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Chrome, Safari 5+, and IE 6+.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox 4+ and Opera.
 */

button,
select {
    text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 * 4. Remove inner spacing in IE 7 without affecting normal text inputs.
 *    Known issue: inner spacing remains in IE 6.
 */

button,
html input[type="button"], /* 1 */
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* 2 */
    cursor: pointer; /* 3 */
    *overflow: visible;  /* 4 */
}

/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}

/**
 * 1. Address box sizing set to content-box in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9.
 * 3. Remove excess padding in IE 7.
 *    Known issue: excess padding remains in IE 6.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
    *height: 13px; /* 3 */
    *width: 13px; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari 5 and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* 2 */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari 5 and Chrome
 * on OS X.
 */

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 3+.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Improve readability and alignment in all browsers.
 */

textarea {
    overflow: auto; /* 1 */
    vertical-align: top; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: rgb(59,173,227);
}


::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

.chromeframe {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Ultimate Shop</title>
 <link href="css/reset.css"    rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/main.css"    rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/adaptive.css"   rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/tooltip.css"   rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main-container">
  <div class="sidebar">
   <div class="logo">
    <a href="/">
     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CKxzxLn.png">
    </a>
   </div>
   <nav>
    <ul>
    </ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rules">
      <a href="#" data-tooltip="Правила" data-tooltip-location="right"></a>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="filters">
     <li class="filter-hidden visible"></li>
     <li class="a-z-background-hidden">
      <div class="a-z-hidden"></div>
     </li>
    </ul>
<!--     <ul>
     <li>
      <input type="number" id="input-range-current-value" oninput="javascript: if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="4">
      <input type="range" class="range pink" min="0" max="9999" value="9999">
     </li>
    </ul> -->
    <ul class="sidebar-bottom">
     <li class="vk">
      <a href="#" data-tooltip="Вконтакте" data-tooltip-location="right"></a>
     </li>
     <li class="telegram">
      <a href="#" data-tooltip="Телеграм" data-tooltip-location="right"></a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот вариант

```css
html {
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #181f4b;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #969dcd;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #FF0000;
}

.unselectable {
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.main-container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c58dd, #2a44c8);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
  width: 40px;
}

nav {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul:first-child,
.sidebar>nav>ul:nth-child(2) {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>li>a {
  color: #6b83e2;
  display: block;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0.3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.personal-office {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>.personal-office>a {
  opacity: 1;
}

.personal-office>a>img:hover {
  transition: 1s;
  transform: rotateZ(360deg);
}

.account_avatar_image {
  width: 48px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
}

.sing-in>a {
  background: url(/images/sing-in.png) no-repeat center;
}

.sing-out>a {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/YwT5mO8.png) no-repeat center;
}

.rules>a {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/N5pzODb.png) no-repeat center;
}

.sing-in>a:hover,
.sing-out>a:hover,
.rules>a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #385ce2;
}

.filters {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.filter-hidden:hover .a-z-background-hidden
/* .filters:hover .a-z-hidden */

{
  display: block;
}

.filter-hidden {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/regS5LD.png) no-repeat center;
}

.filter-hidden {
  color: #6b83e2;
  display: none;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0.3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.filter-hidden>ul {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 48px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.filter-hidden>ul li {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.filter-hidden:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #385ce2;
}

.filter-hidden.visible {
  display: block;
}

.a-z-background-hidden {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c58dd, #2a44c8);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: none;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.a-z-hidden {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/nBI2vJj.png) no-repeat center;
}

.a-z-hidden {
  color: #6b83e2;
  /* display: none; */
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0.3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.vk>a {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Mo1SCNB.png) no-repeat center;
}

.telegram>a {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/IRdCiwG.png) no-repeat center;
}

.vk>a:hover,
.telegram>a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #385ce2;
}

.sidebar-bottom {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}


/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   v2.0-modified | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* make sure to set some focus styles for accessibility */

:focus {
  outline: 0;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  resize: vertical;
}


/**
 * Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 */

audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/**
 * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}


/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 7/8/9, Firefox 3, and Safari 4.
 * Known issue: no IE 6 support.
 */

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}


/**
 * 1. Correct text resizing oddly in IE 6/7 when body `font-size` is set using
 *    `em` units.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */

html {
  font-size: 100%;
  /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
}


/**
 * Address `outline` inconsistency between Chrome and other browsers.
 */

a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
}


/**
 * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}


/**
 * 1. Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 * 2. Improve image quality when scaled in IE 7.
 */

img {
  border: 0;
  /* 1 */
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  /* 2 */
}


/**
 * Address margin not present in IE 6/7/8/9, Safari 5, and Opera 11.
 */

figure {
  margin: 0;
}


/**
 * Correct margin displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

form {
  margin: 0;
}


/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}


/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Correct text not wrapping in Firefox 3.
 * 3. Correct alignment displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

legend {
  border: 0;
  /* 1 */
  padding: 0;
  white-space: normal;
  /* 2 */
  *margin-left: -7px;
  /* 3 */
}


/**
 * 1. Correct font size not being inherited in all browsers.
 * 2. Address margins set differently in IE 6/7, Firefox 3+, Safari 5,
 *    and Chrome.
 * 3. Improve appearance and consistency in all browsers.
 */

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-size: 100%;
  /* 1 */
  margin: 0;
  /* 2 */
  vertical-align: baseline;
  /* 3 */
  *vertical-align: middle;
  /* 3 */
}


/**
 * Address Firefox 3+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */

button,
input {
  line-height: normal;
}


/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Chrome, Safari 5+, and IE 6+.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox 4+ and Opera.
 */

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}


/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 * 4. Remove inner spacing in IE 7 without affecting normal text inputs.
 *    Known issue: inner spacing remains in IE 6.
 */

button,
html input[type="button"],

/* 1 */

input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 2 */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* 3 */
  *overflow: visible;
  /* 4 */
}


/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}


/**
 * 1. Address box sizing set to content-box in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9.
 * 3. Remove excess padding in IE 7.
 *    Known issue: excess padding remains in IE 6.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 2 */
  *height: 13px;
  /* 3 */
  *width: 13px;
  /* 3 */
}


/**
 * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari 5 and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */

input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  /* 1 */
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  /* 2 */
  box-sizing: content-box;
}


/**
 * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari 5 and Chrome
 * on OS X.
 */

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}


/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 3+.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/**
 * 1. Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Improve readability and alignment in all browsers.
 */

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  /* 1 */
  vertical-align: top;
  /* 2 */
}


/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  color: rgb(59, 173, 227);
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.chromeframe {
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Ultimate Shop</title>
  <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/adaptive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/tooltip.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="/">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CKxzxLn.png">
        </a>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li class="rules">
            <a href="#" data-tooltip="Правила" data-tooltip-location="right"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="filters">
          <li class="filter-hidden visible">
            <ul>
              <li class="a-z-background-hidden">
                <div class="a-z-hidden"></div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <!--     <ul>
     <li>
      <input type="number" id="input-range-current-value" oninput="javascript: if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="4">
      <input type="range" class="range pink" min="0" max="9999" value="9999">
     </li>
    </ul> -->
        <ul class="sidebar-bottom">
          <li class="vk">
            <a href="#" data-tooltip="Вконтакте" data-tooltip-location="right"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="telegram">
            <a href="#" data-tooltip="Телеграм" data-tooltip-location="right"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое